# Can $unwind utilize an index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My basic question is that I don't understand how to utilize an index for with an unwind query. I wanted to keep an array inside a document because I thought it would be more performant. But if I can't find a way to make this work my thought is that my only recourse is to have two collections with indexes and then do a $lookup aggregation to enable this. I want to know the following:

1. Can mongo use an index with a document that has an embedded array to cover the query?
2. Do I need to have two collections in order to cover the aggregation query below?

My `client` collection has this structure:

```
{
 _id:{$oid:''},
 clientId:1005,
 displayName:'my client',
 divisions:[
   _id:'division1',
   skillsRequired:[]
 ]
}
```

I have the following index on the `client` collection:

```
  {
    v: 2,
    key: {
      clientId: 1,
      displayName: 1,
      'divisions._id': 1,
      'divisions.skillsRequired': 1
    },
    name: 'client_skills'
  }
```

When I run the following aggregation query and look at the query explanation plan it doesn't use the index above despite that all the fields in the output are in the index? Why is that?

```
db.client.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$divisions"},
    {   $project: {
            clientId:1,
            displayName:1,
            divisionId:"$divisions._id",
            skillsRequired:"$divisions.skillsRequired"
        }
    }
])
```

If you want to see the query plan here it is:

```
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  stages: [
    {
      '$cursor': {
        queryPlanner: {
          namespace: '63ac857fbaf9e86e3f3f9bc1_gps.client',
          indexFilterSet: false,
          parsedQuery: {},
          queryHash: '5CF751FE',
          planCacheKey: '9AA9418D',
          maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
          maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
          maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
          winningPlan: {
            stage: 'PROJECTION_SIMPLE',
            transformBy: { _id: 1, clientId: 1, displayName: 1, divisions: 1 },
            inputStage: { stage: 'COLLSCAN', direction: 'forward' }
          },
          rejectedPlans: []
        },
        executionStats: {
          executionSuccess: true,
          nReturned: 181,
          executionTimeMillis: 1,
          totalKeysExamined: 0,
          totalDocsExamined: 181,
          executionStages: {
            stage: 'PROJECTION_SIMPLE',
            nReturned: 181,
            executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
            works: 183,
            advanced: 181,
            needTime: 1,
            needYield: 0,
            saveState: 1,
            restoreState: 1,
            isEOF: 1,
            transformBy: { _id: 1, clientId: 1, displayName: 1, divisions: 1 },
            inputStage: {
              stage: 'COLLSCAN',
              nReturned: 181,
              executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
              works: 183,
              advanced: 181,
              needTime: 1,
              needYield: 0,
              saveState: 1,
              restoreState: 1,
              isEOF: 1,
              direction: 'forward',
              docsExamined: 181
            }
          },
          allPlansExecution: []
        }
      },
      nReturned: Long("181"),
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: Long("0")
    },
    {
      '$unwind': { path: '$divisions' },
      nReturned: Long("185"),
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: Long("0")
    },
    {
      '$project': {
        _id: true,
        displayName: true,
        clientId: true,
        divisionId: '$divisions._id',
        skillsRequired: '$divisions.skillsRequired'
      },
      nReturned: Long("185"),
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: Long("0")
    }
  ],
  serverInfo: {
    host: 'ac-553hexy-shard-00-02.rvkcvj5.mongodb.net',
    port: 27017,
    version: '5.0.14',
    gitVersion: '1b3b0073a0b436a8a502b612f24fb2bd572772e5'
  },
  serverParameters: {
    internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes: 16793600,
    internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes: 33554432,
    internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS: 0,
    internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600
  },
  command: {
    aggregate: 'client',
    pipeline: [
      { '$unwind': '$divisions' },
      {
        '$project': {
          clientId: 1,
          displayName: 1,
          divisionId: '$divisions._id',
          skillsRequired: '$divisions.skillsRequired'
        }
      }
    ],
    cursor: {},
    '$db': 'gps'
  },
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1675954493, i: 23 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("1bb78d5fc18f3164d4e5d60704192be26fbd2572", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7163328034601173016")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1675954493, i: 23 })
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are retrieving every document in the collection. Indexes are typically most beneficial when the result set represents a small portion of the overall data. What specific benefit or performance change are you hoping to achieve with an index for this query?

Comment: The goal is to use an index to "cover the query". Instead of having to retrieve the entire document just grab the pieces I need. Less data coming from the server and the server doesn't have to do a full collection scan to get the required info. If the collection were millions of rows I imagine this would perform better.

Comment: I don't think you can always make that assumption - there is overhead associated with turning index keys into "documents" that will be returned to the client. It also isn't clear from your question that you are actually looking for a meaningful subset of the fields based on the sample schema provided. Anyway, in addition to what @Joe mentioned in the answer, there is a general limitation associated with your situation (covering when an array is involved) documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query)

Answer (score 0):

When an indexed field contains an array, MongoDB generates a separate entry in the index for every element of the array, but the entire array is not stored in the index.

In the example query, the server could obtain all of the possible values by scanning the index, but it would then have to group the values together by document, and guess at the order of the items in the array.

MongoDB permits flexible schema, so it is not required that all of the documents in the collection have an array in the same field.  This means the server would also have to guess at which field was the index for each document.

Overall it is much simpler and faster, and more importantly, more consistent and correct to read the documents directly.